# Is $S_5$ isomorphic with the direct product $A_5 \times Z_2$?

Tags: group-theory

Is $S_5$ isomorphic with the direct product $A_5 \times Z_2$?
How i can check it?

Comment: No $S^5$ does not have a normal subgroup of order $2$ or nontrivial center.

Answer (score 5):

If it were, then there would be a normal subgroup in $S_5$ of size 2. Is there such a thing?

(No, since you can easily see that any permutation of order $2$ fixes some element, and conjugation could turn that permutation into something that moved that element.)

Comment: $\{e,e\}$ is a normal subgroup of size $2$. Am I wrong?

Comment: $\{x, x\} = \{x\}$ for all $x$, dREaM.

Comment: Yes. But $x\neq e$.

Comment: @dREaM $\{e,e\}$ just redundantly rewrites $e$. It's still a subgroup of order $1$. Think of it this way: $S_5$ has 120 elements, but if you started allowing double-counting of them, you could say it had 5389 elements if you wanted to.

Comment: Now I'm confused. how does $\{e,e\}$ have $5389$ elements?

Comment: @dREaM: It doesn't, it has one element: $e$. Alex is suggesting that you could use a similar "argument" to claim that $$\{e,e,e,...,e\}$$ (with $5389$ $e$'s) had $5389$ elements, but again, this is false. It has one element: $e$.

Comment: e.e${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 2):

You could note that $S_5$ does not contain any element of order $10$.